# xcode 7 swift found nil while unwrapping optional in a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm sorry to be asking yet another "found nil unwrapping optional in TableViewCell" posting, but after hours of debugging and reading other such posts here, I'm still stuck.  I think I've covered all of the usual mistakes, but still can't get things to work.

As a starting point, everything works fine as long as I use the default label in the cell, referenced with "cell.textLabel!.text = mystring." And I have another case where I customized the prototype cell with an image and a label, and that worked fine too.

In the current case, I have a normal UIViewController, with some other views and a UITableView embedded. The normal UIViewController is set as the delegate for the cells.

Here's the SettingsCell.swift code. Pretty simple. The little dot on the left of the Outlet in xcode is solid, showing that the outlet is properly connected to the CellTwo label on my prototype table cell.

```
class SettingsCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var CellTwo: UILabel!

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier reuseID: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

In the corresponding SettingsVC.swift view controller, here is the dequeueCell code that takes the nil fault on trying to set the cell.CellTwo value.

The cells display fine in the table view, but only the default textLabel.txt that is part of the UILabel shows up. My custom label does not show at all.

```
  func tableView(
    tv: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SettingsCell") as! SettingsCell
    let row = indexPath.row

    cell.textLabel!.text = SettingsNames[row]
    // the commented out line below crashes on a nil unwrapped optional
    // cell.CellTwo!.text = "Blah"
    if let b = cell.CellTwo {
      b.text = "Blah"
    }
    return cell
  }
```

With the little "let b =" optional unwrap nil protection, the app does not crash, but my second label doesn't get set either.  Finally, consider registration of the class.

Many examples exist on the net (without using prototypes) where you register the class, and I've done that before successfully. And I've done an example where I built a custom prototype cell, and that one worked fine too. But... I think all those examples were using a UITableViewController, not a normal UIViewController + embedded UITableView. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Anyhow, here is the init / viewDidLoad code in the UIViewController that contains the UITableView. As you can see from the code, the UIViewController claims the datasource and delegate responsibilities, and sure enough, the table rows show up and work fine.

I've tried registration both ways -- without the code registration, and with the code registration line. But it doesn't make any difference at all - my code still crashes on the nil reference to my custom label in the cell.

```
class SettingsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SettingsTV.dataSource = self
    SettingsTV.delegate = self
    // I tried with this line in and out, no difference, the crash still happens
    //SettingsTV.registerClass(SettingsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")
    SettingsTV.estimatedRowHeight = 70
  }
```

It's like my custom label doesn't get created or initialized somehow. But I can't explain it. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In your storyboard did you change the class of your prototype cell to `SettingsCell`? Also, try disconnecting and reconnecting the outlet, sometimes they break. Finally, try creating your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SettingsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I confirm: yes, the storyboard prototype cell is bound to SettingsCell class. I disconnected/reconnected the outlet yet again (I agree, sometimes they go wonky and break). And I changed my "tv" local var to tableView.dequeue as you requested. Sad to say, no change in the results. If I try to assign a value to cell.CellTwo, it takes a nil fault. It seems like I'm casting the "dequeued" (freshly created) cell to a SettingsCell, expecting the cell to actually BE a SettingsCell, where the outlet takes the place of actual Label storage. But it's not really there.

Comment: did you set the reuse identifier in storyboard?

Comment: Oh yes, I checked that many times. The key answer (I think) was that the NSCoder init had to call super.init() in the NSCoder required init block. See my (many) postings on this thread...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my issue was in the initialization of the SettingsCell shown in the first block of code above. That initialization sequence was copied from an example that worked fine, but that DID NOT USE THE STORYBOARD. Instead, that example just limited itself to using the default textLabel.text fields in the UITableViewCell definition.

To solve the problem, I just kept going back through my examples trying to recreate the problem in examples that already worked. Here's the key.

If you use the storyboard with a prototype cell, the table cell initialization cannot look like the first block in this posting!! That style only works for non-storyboard cells.

Instead, it should look like this one below. Notice that I commented out the default code that xcode inserts into the file when it is created. So you can basically have an empty class for the cell, as long as you have places for the Outlets.

```
        class SettingsCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var XXXLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var CellTwo: UILabel!

      //      override func awakeFromNib() {
      //        super.awakeFromNib()
      //        // Initialization code
      //      }
      //
      //      override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      //        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      //
      //        // Configure the view for the selected state
      //      }
    }
```

A second thing that showed up was that the two labels on the storyboard were placed at either end of the any-any size storyboard. And my constraints put the right hand label off the edge of the simulated device. I happened to rotate the device in the simulator, and presto! there was the second label. I should use the previewer more regularly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining your custom cell in a seperate XIB instead of using prototype cells in the tableview? It is pretty much the same as what you did but it just has another XIB file out of the storyboard. To create the XIB:

File -> New File -> iOS -> User Interface ->Empty
Drag a UITableViewCell to the XIB and customize accordingly. Set its class to SettingsCell and wire up the labels, etc... to your SettingsCell class

Then in your VC you register it like this:

```
 let nibName = UINib(nibName: "SettingsCell", bundle:nil)
 self.SettingsTV.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. But sorry to say, I don't know a thing about NIBs or XIBs... And I figured out what was going on and documented it here.

Comment: Great that you got it all worked out. All the best in your development. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another part of the answer is in the contents of the NSCoder required init block shown at the top of this post. That block was copied from a working example that did NOT use a storyboard prototype cell. So I often took a fatal error when I tried that with my prototype tableview cell.

Here is what that block SHOULD (must) look like if you are using a prototype cell. The required NSCoder must call the super.init, like so:

```
      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      }
```

It's odd that when xcode auto-fixes the NSCoder issue by injecting a template NSCoder required init? function, it injects one that will break with prototype cells. Why not add the super.init(..) line instead of the fatal error line? Probably there's a reason, but not one that I can see.

Anyhow, all this works for me now, even with a prototype storyboard table view. So I think that's all the questions/issues resolved for this one.